# Confidence intervals on the derivative of a polynomial surface

Tags: linear-regression, confidence-interval, derivative

My problem is the following:

I have fit a surface to some xyz coordinate data to obtain a polynomial surface. That's a polynomial in the variables x and y giving a surface of z-values. I know how to compute 95 percent condidence intervals on the mean response and also new predicition intervals (the standard stuff). Having obtained the surface function it's also easy to determine the derivative at a certain point on the the surface however, what I'm looking for is:

**How do I compute confidence levels on the derivative value dS/dx, the (partial) derivative in the x direction at a certain point?**

Are there expressions for calculating such intervals similar to the intervals for the 95 percent confidence intervals on the mean response?

(Please don't bother to post an answer on the confidence interval for the slope of a simple regression line. That's not the answer to this question. Anyway, I think it isn't.)

Comment: This is probably better suited to Cross Validated than Stack Overflow. As I read your question, it's about methods, not coding (yet).

Comment: Right, copied it there. I don't know how to migrate it appropriately...